# Xcode 9: method parameter not available in debugger?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I've got an issue where I'm calling a method with generic a generic parameter that works properly (at runtime, the parameter is visible to the method), however in the Xcode debugger, the parameter is "not there").

The definition of the method looks like this:

```
func updateCacheObject<T: PLObjectCacheable>(newCacheObject: T) throws -> T {
    NSLog("CacheObject.cacheId: \(newCacheObject.cacheId)")
    let cachedObject: T? = try self.getCacheObject(id: newCacheObject.cacheId)

    ...
```

Where the PLObjectCacheable is defined as:

```
protocol PLObjectCacheable {
    var cacheId: String { get }
    var isFullObject: Bool { get }
    func mergeWithOldObject(_ oldObject: Self?) -> Self
    static func getCacheIdForString(id: String) -> String
    var cacheDate: Date { get }
}
```

and an implementation of a class that implements PLObjectCacheable is this:

```
struct FullTrack: PLObjectCacheable {
    let id: String
    var cacheId: String {
        return self.id
    }
    var isFullObject: Bool {
        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

So, going back to the `updateCacheObject` method, when it's called, the first line dumps out the `newCacheObject` parameter's `cacheId` member variable.

This works fine.

However, if I place a breakpoint in the Xcode debugger anywhere in the method, Xcode can't "see" the `newCacheObject` parameter.

See the image:

[image: xcode debugger information]

Note that the Blue/Cyan square shows that the `newCacheObject.cacheId` was successfully logged.

The Red and purple squares show that the debugger can't find the `newCacheObject` variable.

Is it because it's a generic parameter? I'm confused.

Thanks.